# Text search through multiple file encoding

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, ascii, java.util.scanner

I am trying to find a specific word from list of files and these files can be ASCII, Unicode or some other format. 
So far I can only work on ASCII files . Is there any way to do same operation with other file encoding formats.

```
Scanner s = null;

        try {

            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\New Microsoft Word Document.docx")));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
//               final String lineFromFile = s.nextLine();
//              if(lineFromFile.contains("DE")){
                    System.out.println(s.next());
//                    break;
//              }

            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
```

I get the following results

```
Q[µM¡°‰”Ø÷Þ3{:½¹®’)xTÖä¬?µXFÚB™QÎÞ‡Ïé=K0SˆÊÈÙ?õº×W?áÂ&¤6˜³qî?s”cÐ3ëÀÐJi½?^ýˆ;!¿Äøm«uÇ¥5LHCô`ÝÎ”bR…¤?§Ï+gF,y\í‹Q9S:êãw~Pá¡Â=‰p®RRª?OM±Ç•®™2R.÷àX9¼!ð#
qe—i;`­{¥fzU@2>¼Mä|f}Á
+'šªÎNÛ
```

Comment: What you are tried already?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759356/what-is-the-most-accurate-encoding-detector) may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

docx is not a text format with a different encoding, it's a completely different, non-text file format. Basically, it'a zip archive of various files and folders (with the main data in some xml files). You can't just read it as a text file, you need to use a library such as Apache POI, or some kind of file converter to obtain the text from it.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with a different text encoding.

**[docx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)** is a special format from microsoft which holds various information about a document (packed as a zip archive).

You could read the file using java [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile%28java.io.File%29) and get the entry: **word/document.xml** 
document.xml contains the text of the word document. You can read then through this file and output specific lines.

Pseudocode:

```
ZipFile file = new ZipFile("doc.docx");
InputStream input = file.getInputStream(file.getEntry("word/document.xml"));
```

*input* contains now the text information.

**EDIT:** document.xml contains the text of the document, but there are many xml tags which you would have to filter out

Comment: its clear docx is just one file but i also have other unicode files. Do u know any api for unicoded files

Comment: java is able to read those :D maybe you want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441490/whats-the-difference-between-an-encoding-a-character-set-and-a-code-page